# Analyze the results of the sql query : dbcc showcontig

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How can I analyze the results of the sql query : `dbcc showcontig` to improve the performance of sql?

Comment: You might be better off using the SQL Server Database Tuning Advisor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494.aspx

Comment: It might also help posting the query you wish to improve.

Comment: astander - He said "DBCC SHOWCONTIG" was the query. I thought that was quite clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results from SHOWCONTIG are relevant only if you have a clustered index on the table. Books Online has a nice section about this.

Depending on the fragmentation level (~20% - 30%), you will decide whether to simply defrag the indexes, or rebuild them completely. This also depends on the number of changed rows, the total number of data pages, etc.

If you choose to defrag the indexes, remember to update your statistics as a separate step. This happens automatically when you rebuild.

> EDIT: (From Books Online for SQL 2008)
>
> This feature will be removed in the
>   next version of Microsoft SQL Server.
>   Avoid using this feature in new
>   development work, and plan to modify
>   applications that currently use this
>   feature. Use
>   sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
>   instead.

Comment: send the link to the nice page on msdn please

Comment: This is to the SQL 2000 page, but the information is still relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258803%28SQL.80,lightweight%29.aspx. Here's a link to Paul Randal's blog for more information about this section: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Where-do-the-Books-Online-index-fragmentation-thresholds-come-from.aspx